# Como eliminar espacios vacíos del nombre de una imagen

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente duda, estoy validando las imágenes que subo mediante un input FILE, para así poder eliminar los espacios en blanco del nombre de la imagen, para así reemplazarlos por un guion, la imagen de ejemplo, a sido generada con CANVA y tiene por nombre

```
TU OUTLET (800 × 800 px).png
```

El script PHP es el siguiente:

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES[$input]['tmp_name'][$i]; 
$fileSize = $_FILES[$input]['size'][$i];
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES[$input]['name'][$i], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$fileName = $_FILES[$input]['name'][$i];
echo 'Imagen sin espacios '. preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-',$fileName).'<br>';
echo mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/[\s-]+/', '-',$fileName)).'<br>';
```

Pero en el resultado final no se eliminan todos los espacios, devolviendo lo siguiente:

```
Imagen sin espacios TU-OUTLET-(800 × 800 px).png
tu-outlet-(800 × 800 px).png
```

Comment: Pasa que los caracteres entre `800 × 800 px` no son espacios. [Acá se puede ver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4XWV.png). Quizas lo mejor sería reemplazar todo lo que sea distinto de lo que si aceptas

Comment: La función [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) funciona 100% para estos casos.

Comment: ahí me perdí un poco ósea claro los nombre de imágenes solo podrán tener letras de la a-z, números y paréntesis, como lo hago para reemplazar todo lo que sea distinto a eso ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En base a [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/592986/como-eliminar-espacios-vac%c3%ados-del-nombre-de-una-imagen#comment1047651_592986):

> [...] los nombre de imágenes solo podrán tener letras de la a-z, números y paréntesis, como lo hago para reemplazar todo lo que sea distinto a eso ?

Para reemplzar todos aquellos caracteres distintos de:

- A-Z
- 0-9
- Parentesis

Podrías usar esta RegEx:

```
/[^a-zA-Z0-9()]+/
```

#### Ejemplo:

```php
$fileName = 'TU OUTLET (800 × 800 px).png';
echo 'Imagen sin espacios '. preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9()]+/', '-',$fileName).'<br>';
echo mb_strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9()]+/', '-',$fileName)).'<br>';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://onlinephp.io/c/7eaec)</kbd>

Comment: muchas gracias, me sirvio mucho

Answer (score 0):

Y no te sale más fácil hacerlo con funciones de PHP?

```
<?php
$imgName = 'TU OUTLET (800 × 800 px).png';
echo $result = strtolower(str_replace(" ", "-", $imgName));
// tu-outlet-(800-×-800-px).png
```

Primero haces un reemplazo de los espacios por un guion (-), luego lo conviertes a minúsculas y listo!!!